# How can I remove the cover of a shaver outlet/light to repair a faulty switch?

Tags: light-fixture

Here is my bathroom shaver light:

[image]

It's only a few months old, but it recently developed a fault: the light comes on when you pull the string (hanging from the left in the picture) to the half-way point, but it goes out when you pull the string any further. So you have to keep holding the string if you want the light to stay on. That's the first problem.

So naturally I decided to take the cover off and see if anything looks broken. But I can't get the blasted thing off! That's the second problem. My previous light had four lugs, along the top and bottom edges, and you just squeezed the cover to remove it. But this cover is attached at the ends. Here is a close-up:

[image]

I assume that darker strip to the right of the Half-Bearded Man is what's holding the cover on; there's another one at the other end. I have tried snapping the cover off, but it won't move. Is there a trick to this that I'm too stupid to see? I tried inserting a screwdriver, but there is no gap.

Here is a bottom view of the left-hand end:

[image]

I'm renting, so this is probably something that the landlord should do. But he has been very good in the past, and I would like to do this myself if I can. At least to the extent of getting that damn cover off.

Comment: Provide make/model info might be helpful. Someone _ahem_ could search the internet to find an owners manual that will probably show _exactly_ how to get the cover off.

Comment: @FreeMan, there is no identifying information on the exterior. Perhaps such info is available under the cover...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try squeezing the translucent cover at the back edges near one end and pulling. Chances are a lip engages a channel in the base, akin to a tire bead.

If that doesn't work, try slipping a thin knife under the back edge, then prying outward gently. There appears to be some tabs inside that may need to be cleared.

It's possible that the pull switch is a modular unit which can be replaced. It's also possible that it's proprietary and integrated, in which case you'll need to replace the fixture or bypass the pull switch and install some other type of switch.

Comment: Ha! I got it done! Your advice was almost right: I had to slip a thin knife under the back edge, then shimmy it around to the front, and pry outward _roughly_.

Comment: The back and front aren't the same?

Comment: I inserted the knife in the lower edge, as seen in the third photo. Then I slid it around to the front, as seen in the second photo. (And it looks like the switch problem was just shoddy workmanship -- the return wire was not screwed into the switch. I have to wait until tomorrow for sufficient daylight, but I am optimistic that I can fix it.)